# Ember qunit test causing re-render error when an img's src is set to a computed property

Tags: ember.js, emblem.js

I have a template that renders just fine in production and development, but during my qunit tests, it keeps crashing with the error:

```
Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM
```

The line causing this error reads (using emblem.js):

```
img src=logoUrl
```

The error stops if I change the source to a static path:

```
img src="/assets/logo.png"
```

Curiously, even if I have the computed property return "/assets/logo.png", it still crashes:

```
  logoUrl: (->
    return "/assets/logo.png"
  ).property("projectLogo.file.url")
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: can you show the entire template, and I'm not sure what that translates into either, so I don't know whether or not it's translating it to an img tag, or a bind-attr.  Would you mind translating it to handlebars?

Comment: While converting this to handlebars, I found that there was a second line that was linked to the error. Specifically, it was a component that was being called recursively. When I removed it, everything else worked. I fixed the error in the component, but I'm unsure why it was only bugging out if there was also a computed property for the img. The error is resolved, but if you want to know the true source, I'd be happy to continue debugging with you.

Comment: Also, by the way, thanks for all your help. If I ever have an Ember-related issue, you're the first one (and typically only one) to response. You've been a huge help!

Comment: You're totally welcome, yeah, I'd love to see the recursive component